# Windows 8.1 wont copy or move files to external HDD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, file-transfer, usb-3

I don't know what happened because it used to work perfectly but now I can't copy or move files TO the drive (can still copy them from it to windows) the drive is not corrupt or anything and can be accessed perfectly from Mint, Ubuntu and Win7. The only error I get is a process timeout, both with file explorer and teracopy.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you changed something that would affect your permissions?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware problem. any how try command prompt to copy

```
C:\Users\xxx>copy C:\sourceFolder F:\destinationFolder
```